# zip() isnt working the way it is supposed to

Tags: python, python-itertools

guys see the code and the output i got

```py
import itertools as it
ranks = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
suits = ['H', 'D', 'C', 'S']
cards = it.product(ranks,suits)

l = []
for i in range(5):
    l.append(it.islice(cards,2))

print(list(zip(*l)))
```

```
[(('A', 'H'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'S'), ('K', 'H')), (('K', 'D'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'S'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'D'))]
```

This is the output i got
but shouldnt the output be like below

```
[(('A', 'H'), ('A','C') ,('K', 'H'),('K', 'C'),('Q', 'H')) , (('A', 'D'), ('A', 'S'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'S') , ('Q', 'D'))] this is the expected output
```

i dont know why zip function is working like this here , can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you need to convert the islice object to list `l.append(list(it.islice(cards,2)))`:

```
import itertools as it
ranks = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
suits = ['H', 'D', 'C', 'S']
cards = it.product(ranks,suits)
l = []
for i in range(5):
    l.append(list(it.islice(cards,2))) # here

print(list(zip(*l)))
```

Prints:

```
[(('A', 'H'), ('A', 'C'), ('K', 'H'), ('K', 'C'), ('Q', 'H')), (('A', 'D'), ('A', 'S'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'S'), ('Q', 'D'))]
```

Comment: i tried the zip function with ( zip(iter(l1) , iter(l2) ) other iterators but they worked perfectly why does it behave like this here , like zipping at the middle

Answer (score 0):

This is rather difficult topic but the key idea is that islice and zip function are 'lazy', which means they are efficient. (These functions access elements one-by-one and cannot go backwards. In comparison, constructing a whole list in advance is expensive operation)

You have made "l" a list of 5 iterators.
It doesn't imply that first element of "l" would represent the first 2 tuples(1st&2nd) of the product, and second element of "l" would represent the next 2 tuples(3rd&4th) etc. They are just 5 iterators on the product 'cards'.

Now zip function is executed on 5 elements of list "l".
To compute the first zipped element, lazy 5 iterators are sequentially executed.
First iterator(=l[0]) takes the first element of 'cards' (=AH)
Second iterator(=l[1]) takes the second element of 'cards' (=AD)
.. and so on.
That explains your output.

Now here's another interesting idea.

what if you put a print("cards: ", list(card)) line
after the initialization of variable 'cards'? would it change the output of the code?
It's just a print statement so intuitively it shouldn't change the behavior of program apart from printing some line. But it **does**.

```
import itertools as it
ranks = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
suits = ['H', 'D', 'C', 'S']
cards = it.product(ranks,suits)
print("cards: ", list(cards)) ''' comment this line to get your original output, 
uncomment to make list(zip(*l)) return [] '''
l = []
for i in range(5):
l.append(it.islice(cards,2))
print(l)
print("zip: ", list(zip(*l)))
```

why is list(zip(*l)) empty list now?
While printing 'list(cards)' we used the iterator on 'cards' until it reached the StopIteration. This is because we made the whole list of it.
since we used it, the next(iter(cards)) will raise StopIteration error.
Therefore, when elements of list "l" try to iterate over 'cards', they can't because it's already at the end of iteration. (StopIteration)

What we should learn from this is that iterators are very tricky to use, but they are powerful when used correctly. Just like pointers and memory allocations are dangerous but powerful, same goes for iterator and generators. When you reuse iterator of an object over and over(in this case iterator on cards was reused a lot), it is good to make a solid list of the results and save it, rather than leave it as a floating, dangerous iterators.

Comment: In addition, if you change the line where 'cards' is assigned to make the product into list as soon as it's created, i.e: cards=list(it.product(ranks,suits)), then list(zip(*l)) now returns 5 consecutive AH and then 5 consecutive AD. I think by now you would be able to understand why. In summary, turn islice objects into lists as soon as they are created. that way you can determine what they actually represent  as you intended. But do not turn the it.project object (=cards) into list since that makes all 5 iterators in list 'l' point to the very first element of cards.

Comment: i cant understand the last line you said , what is the it.project object(=cards) , what is that

Comment: does zip behave like this only with islice , i tried passing itertools.product objects with zip and it worked fine , and obviously iterators of list, tuples worked fine as well

Comment: @shady last line is related to this problem specifically. and this problem isn't raised by a peculiar behavior of zip function, rather from misunderstanding how iterators work under the hood. there are two types of iterables. one is like list. you can always see all the elements of it.  the other is like product, range, islice etc. those are lazy objects so when you print them, you can't see individual element content. you have to iterate through it and access elements one by one. and in this problem, it was caused because 5 islice objects iterated through a single product

Comment: in that case those 5 islice objects will share a single iterator on product since that's how product, range etc are built. those 'lazy yet efficient' iterables can be iterated once and only once. you can't expect the 5 islice to iterate independently on a single product. on the other hand if it was a iteration on list, it is possible.

Comment: however what the questioner wanted was not individual and independent iteration of 5 islices. what he/she wanted was to change specific order of iteration between islice objects. therefore, leave product as product, to make 5 iterations be dependent on each other, but change the order between them, by making islices into list. That way, as soon as islice is created, since they now have to be list, they are executed. they can't be lazy anymore. and since they are executed, now the order is that, the first islice takes the first 2 elements of product, and the second one takes the next two elem

Comment: and so on, so the first islice(L[0]) takes 1,2nd elem in cards, L[1] takes 3,4th elem in cards, L[2] takes 5,6th elem in cards , L[3] takes 7,8th elem in cards , L[4] takes 9,10th elem in cards. this is what questioner wanted and it's done. and now if you want to iterate over that cards product once again, you can't. it has done 1 partial iteration already, and iterator is stuck at the 11th element of cards.. you can't do a full iteration on objects like product, range.. twice or more. you can only do it once. Try adding a for loop on cards after the zip is done. it will start from  QC not AH

Comment: Look at it this way. when you form a list, all the elements are in memory. you can iterate over it by how many times you want. but, things like map, range, product, islice don't save all the elements in memory when they are created. it just creates one element at a time when it is called. Therefore doing full iteration twice or more on it is impossible. However their strength is that they don't take up a lot of memory space. same goes for zip function. it doesn't make a whole new chained tuple in memory. in python 2 zip function used to make a whole new tuple in memory, while izip didn't

Comment: now in python3 zip works like izip by default

Comment: mate , see this list -> l = [ ( 1 , 2 ) , ( 3 , 4 ) , ( 5 , 6 ) ] relate it to the cards ( it.product object ) , now i am gonna do -> l = iter( l ) which by the way , once iterated we cannot step back right , and i am going to do what i did above , append to a list with islice( l , 1 ) and i am gonna print( list ( zip (*l ) ) ) , but it worked fine , i got the expected output -> [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)] zip function zips the first element from all the iterators and zip them  as it is supposed to do , but when passing the cards ( it.product object) to islice it didnt work the same way

Comment: both iter( l ) and it.product are iterator objects then why are they behaving like this